# CSS div background-color bug on chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, reactjs

I'm having trouble setting the background of a div in Chrome Browser. If you see, I have a small lighter grey box that I didnt implement and give style. It appears randomly and moves and reshapes as it wants. It doesn't happen on Safari or on Firefox and I can't understand why or either how to fix it.

[image: Chrome bug print-screen]

My problem is quite strange. I have the following code:

```
div className="row competition">
   <div className="col-lg-6 register-answer">
       <div className="compet-content">
           <input type="text" className="form-control answer" id="usr"/>
           <input type="text" className="form-control email" id="usr"/>
           <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Enter Competition</button>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div className="col-lg-6">
       <div className="pic">
           <img src={CompetitionImage} alt="Competition Image"/>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Edited (CSS classes):

```
.col-lg-6.register-answer {
    background-color: #adadad;
    .compet-content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        input {

        }
        button {

        }
    }
}
```

I'm setting the backgound-color on 'register-answer' class but I tried at every div and the problem is always the same (it only happens on chrome).
I have a screen recording also for you to see: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9yzCbrCAKvKRVE3VmNJNmhqLVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you make one jsfiddle?

Comment: @devnull69 I'm using react, you can see on my tags.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson I edited the question and I wrote the css class there.

Comment: What's the problem..?

Comment: @chiragpatel I would but it's not easy to reproduce this error on jsfiddle, I've tried with the same code I have and it's not happening there.

Comment: @Lee the small lighter grey box in the middle... It's always moving and reshaping and I'm not building and giving style for that anywhere. I just have a div (bootstrap col-lg-6) and I give it a backgroud color.

Comment: Looks like the padding that `.col-lg-6` has been set maybe?

Comment: If it's not happening anywhere else, then i'd look through your inspector and see if there's any other CSS rules being loaded that are being interfered with.

Comment: @Lee, nop, not because of the padding. I took out the padding: 0; and still the same issue.

Comment: Create a JSFiddle, even if it doesn't do the same thing, so that others can at least try and replicate it.

Comment: @Lee ok, just a min.

Comment: Here's a properly working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/o75sn59x/ and I must add that it's not doing anything weird for me

Comment: @Lee https://jsfiddle.net/0zvvudhd/1/

Comment: @MiguelVeloso have you checked if you have some unclosed tags in your code somewhere which might cause your problems since the demo doesn't seem to bug? Or does it bug for you?

Comment: @thepio I have it like it's here and on jsfiddle up here. Every tag is closed and tried many things till now, but the bug still the same

Comment: That link you sent me has nested CSS declarations, which you can't use. That's why no background colour is showing int he JSFiddle.

Comment: @Lee you can just actually choose from the CSS settings for it to use SCSS and it works. But it doesn't bug for me in any way.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for that tip @thepio. I don't use SCSS. Hmm strange, there must be something specific on the posters machine/setup that's doing this. Doesn't appear to be a bug.

Comment: Sorry @Lee, I didn't mention that I'm using SCSS. I tried everything and I can't take this bug out. I have pages and pages implemented and is the only section where I had this problem.

Comment: @Lee I guess I found the issue, but it is so strange... The last component on my body (using react) will have this bug - still don't know why. If had a div with random text like "asd" on the bottom, this component will stop having this bug. Don't ask me why, cause is a good question!

Comment: This render bug in chrome is still present.  Very simple example... https://jsfiddle.net/tmonster/0kaajkoL/

Answer (score 11):

I'm also having this problem and found this: http://www.parallaxinfotech.com/blog/addressing-css-artifacts-left-screen-chrome

Tried the solution... `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` in the rule where I specify `background-color` (`body`, in my case) and that worked. Still looking for a better solution.

**UPDATE:** Looks like this is a [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=633805). If you want to solve it for all your visitors, the hack above seems to work. If you want to solve it for just you, you can go to `chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization` and enable GPU rasterization. I imagine this bug will be fixed by the Chrome team soon enough, so I decided not to use the hack.

Comment: translate3d DOES work! But it also happens to turn all position: fixed elements into position: absolute, so that kind of ruined it for me.

Chrome, the new IE6

Comment: Thanks so much! We were tearing our hair out on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with the same issue.

I've noticed that if you add a border to the element where the background colour is applied, the light box disappears.

If it doesn't interfere with your design, I would suggest adding a border that's the same colour as your background.

In your case:

```
.col-lg-6.register-answer {
    border: 1px solid #adadad;
}
```

Or, if you're feeling adventurous try an (almost) transparent background with background-clip: padding-box. Your transparency has to be > 0 for the hack to work. I set mine to 0.01 and it does the trick (i.e. rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.01).

Answer (score 0):

try adding background-color: transparent on the divs that you wish for the grey background to appear on

Comment: I just have a div on top of the one that has the background-color (the one that holds the input and button). I set it transparent and nothing changed. I already tried to set the background in other divs and the problem still the same.